# Mixing 3 searches by Laravel Query and Eloquent

Tags: laravel-query-builder

I try to make 3 queries by use Laravel Eloquent and Query builder.
My first tried was worked find with divided each others how first one is search by user_name & customer_name and another one by date, but not working when I mixed these 3 queries. I think the order of declaration seems to be wrong. could you help me?

[image]

```
public function job_history_search(Request $request) 
{ 
   $jobs = Job::where('user_name', 'like', '%'.$request->name.'%')
   ->orWhere('customer_name', 'like', '%'.$request->name.'%')
   ->whereBetween('created_at', array(
   (Carbon::parse($request->input('datepicker_from'))->startOfDay()),
   (Carbon::parse($request->input('datepicker_to'))->endOfDay())))
   ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc') 
   ->paginate(15);

   return view('jobs.index', ['jobs' => $jobs]); 
}
```

Comment: For optimization use LIKE in SQL with no % at the beginning only at the end to use SQL Index for a faster result.

Comment: @Disfigure, thanks, Is that any solution instead of using % for search text?:)

Comment: You can use it, there is no problem at all using it. Just perfom your search like $request->name.'%'.

Answer (score 1):

You should perform your where clause like that :

```
Job::where(function ($query) use ($request) {
    return $query->where('customer_name', 'LIKE', $request->name . '%')
          ->orWhere('user_name', 'LIKE', $request->name .'%');
})
 ->whereBetween('created_at', array(
     (Carbon::parse($request->input('datepicker_from'))->startOfDay()),
     (Carbon::parse($request->input('datepicker_to'))->endOfDay())))
 ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc') 
 ->paginate(15);
```

For optimization use LIKE in SQL with no % at the beginning,use it only at the end of the LIKE statement to use SQL Index for a faster result

Comment: thanks.. but there has been error...

(1/1) ErrorException
Undefined variable: request

Comment: sorry i forgot to add the use on the callback, I edited the post

Comment: not working, can't see view after click search button... now I debuging ...thanks.:)

Comment: Try it now, It's been a while for me using Eloquent QueryBuilder, maybe its the return statement i forgot into the callback :)

Comment: is there needs two different arguments for using two $request values?

Comment: what do you mean by two differents arguments ?

Comment: in my code, there are two different type of input data with date and name(user or customer), so in this case, how can this code working with different request inputs? :( thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I know you're saying but you could do some condition regarding of data type and perform the search